# Error con blucle for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hoy inicie con el  bucles for con un pequeño programa que tiene como función imprimir si un correo electrónico esta bien o esta mal de una forma muy básica[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema radica en la linea 5 donde le describo al programa que si tiene arroba(@) y de final ".com" la variable email va hacer verdadera y tendrá como propósito imprimir el mensaje "es correcto el correo" lo cual no la se esta ejecutando y pasa a la lineal del condicional else  sabiendo que el correo si tiene arroba"@" y el ."com"

les quería pedir su ayuda

PD:no sabia que escribir en el titulo
gracias
perdon por la ortografia me estan fallando las teclas del teclado

Comment: Nunca adjuntes código con capturas, si deseas adjuntar código la manera correcta es copiarlo en la pregunta, seleccionarlo y presionas `Ctrl + K`.

Comment: Si adjuntas el código de la manera adecuada podrás obtener una respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: `i` en el `for` representa cada letra, nunca va a ser igual a "@" e (`and`) igual a ".com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema con tu código es el ya mencionado, ocurre que el for evalúa elemento por elemento en este caso sería letra por letra y una sola letra nunca va a ser igual a .com y por eso no funciona.
Hay varias formas de hacerlos desde sencillas como proponen arriba hasta complicadas, pero si quieres hacerlo con for por fines didácticos, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
isMail = False #la variable isMail esta en false de inicio
email = 'user@mail.com' #puedes cambiarla por cualquier texto a validar
for i in email: #Recorre toda la cadena buscando @
    if(i =='@'):
        if('.com' in email): #solo si encuentra la @ prosedera
            isMail = True #si encuentra .com entones la variable isMail cambia a true
if(isMail): print('Es un correo') #Si la variable es verdadera imprime Es un correo
else: print('No es correo') #caso contrario imprime no es correo
```

Si quieres practicar más puedes hacer que después del punto se guarden los siguientes 3 caracteres en una variable temporal y luego ver si es igual a com. Obvio estas no son las formas optimas pero como practicas están bien, saludos.

Comment: gracias me ayudaste mucho

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el bucle for en cada iteracion se iguala a un caracter de la cadena, es imposible que sea igual a "@" y ".com", para lo que quieres hacer puedes usar la funcion .count(), esta funcion recibe como parametro lo que quieres contar dentro de una cadena y retorna el numero de veces que se encuentra en la cadena.

```
print("junchaconar@gmail.com".count("@gmail.com"))
```

output:   `1`

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda